# Unable to pass query result using findById

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on Blog using Node and mongoose. in the index page I am able to show all the posts but on clicking the title to see complete post `null` values is showing. href links have been inserted correctly and it is redirecting to the desired link "http://localhost:3000/posts/show/596e795be0a91a1cdcc572eb". I tried passing the query by id.
**posts.js ->routes**

```
var posts = require('../models/posts');

router.get('/show/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    posts.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post){
        console.log(post);
        res.render('show',{
            "post": post
        });
    });
});
```

**posts.js-> models**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var lists = new Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author:{
        type: String
    },
    _id:{
        type: String,

    },
    category:{
        type: String
    },
    body:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

var posts = module.exports = mongoose.model('posts', lists);
```

**show.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    .show
        h1 #{post.title}
        p.meta Posted in
            a(href='/categories/show/#{post.category}')  #{post.category}
            span  by 
            a(href='/posts/show/#{post.author}') #{post.author} on #{moment(post.date).format("DD-MMM-YYYY")}
        img(src='/images/uploads/#{post.mainimage}')
        !=post.body
        br
        hr
```

**output**

> 596e795be0a91a1cdcc572eb
>   null

I have been stuck on this error for a long time. Read and tried all possible solutions on this site. Even went through the mongoose doc. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please help.Thanks

Comment: Somehow I don't believe that these `ObjectId` looking values are actually stored as `String`. I think you wrote your schema after the data already existed and therefore the `_id:{  type: String }` should not be there. Instead remove the definition and let mongoose/mongodb do it's default thing. You get `null` because "nothing matches". And "nothing matches" because the value is actually an `ObjectId`. So don't define a schema that says otherwise.

Comment: Not sure if this causes the issue, but try replacing `var posts = module.exports = mongoose.model('posts', lists);`  by  `var posts = mongoose.model('posts', lists);`   `module.exports = posts;`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you mate, I removed _id from the schema and now it is working fine. Worked magically. :D

Comment: @DrunkDevKek I did that before, but was of no help. BTW thank you